# When run docker-compose up I get python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.1

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add requirements (to leverage Docker cache)
ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
ADD . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  users-service:
    container_name: users-service
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5001:5000 # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
```

This is structure of my project dir (from which I run my docker commands):

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── env
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── lib64 -> lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   ├── pyvenv.cfg
│   └── share
├── manage.py
├── project
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
└── requirements.txt
```

First I run **docker-compose build** and get following output:

```
Building users-service
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6.1
 ---> 74145628c331
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8b73b9540da2
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 28d3452f6021
Step 4/7 : ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e92c334820c2
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db7ea8211cd1
Step 6/7 : ADD . /usr/src/app
 ---> 472c303e4297
Removing intermediate container 7ee1b497cde4
Step 7/7 : CMD python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
 ---> Running in 31ae97876314
 ---> 42c79e68f692
Removing intermediate container 31ae97876314
Successfully built 42c79e68f692
Successfully tagged flaskmicroservicesusers_users-service:latest
```

And then I run **docker-compose up** which return error:

```
Recreating users-service
Attaching to users-service
users-service    | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
users-service exited with code 2
```

**What I am missing here?**

Comment: Have you tried following [this](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application) guide? It's likely you missed up on a step setting the root project directory or linking the Python `manage.py` file.

Comment: @AdeelAhmad I am following [this tutorial](http://testdriven.io/part-one-docker-config/). I will now check the one you posted.

Comment: Could you run `docker-compose run --rm users-service pwd` and/or `docker-compose run --rm users-service ls`, to see what working directory the container starts in and what's in it?

Comment: @Arjen docker-compose run --rm users-service pwd return /usr/src/app and docker-compose run --rm users-service ls return nothing.

Comment: When you run `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`, can you find your sources ?

Comment: @WassimDhif I closed my terminal and open it again and now everything works fine when I run build and up commands. With your command I also get all my files. I am not sure why in new terminal session everything works?

Comment: Well beats me, but everything works then I guess your good.

Comment: Your output from the docker-compose build command is showing that you are just getting existing cached layers. I would recommend showing a build that is not simply just a fully cached run.

Comment: What happens if you do `docker run --rm -it flaskmicroservicesusers_users-service:latest bash` ? Are you able to see manage.py on the file system? Is it a symbolic link?

Comment: Hi Luka, I have added a new answer which was happened to me, I think it is the most appropriate and helpful answer.

Answer (score 26):

Remove volumes from docker-compose.yml and build again.

```
version: '2.1'
services:
users-service:
  container_name: users-service
  build: .
  ports:
    - 5001:5000 # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
```

there is an issue with docker-compose on ubuntu. it can't mount the volume. And as I can see you want to mount `.` to `/usr/src/app`

You would need to build the image again after you update the code.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks for the trick. [docker-compose, version: ‘3.7’]

Comment: So it's just not possible to use volumes?

Comment: @NajlaBioinfo Thanks, I also had the same issue. Removing the volume mount worked, but I need the volume to be mounted, is there any workaround?

Comment: Fartash jan I have added a new answer, I would be thankful if you could review it. :) Thanks

Comment: @MartínSchere take a look at the answer I just posted. It is possible to use bind mounts with ubuntu.

Comment: My problem was (bind mounts are working), that i used this approach to do live changes to the source code during development. But on the target machine i used the same compose file, but there the source code did not exist. So the bin mount overwrote the existing manage.py with nothing and thus manage.py could not be found.

Answer (score 5):

Do not run your application in a docker-machine vm by running this `eval $(docker-machine env <your-vm>`. But if you have, unlink the docker-machine by running `eval $(docker-machine env -u)`

Answer (score 5):

As @Fartash said, there is a problem with mounting the folder as volume in ubuntu. In order to resolve the error you can use `named volume` in docker.

You can simply defining new named volume in `docker-compose` file as below:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  users-service:
    container_name: users-service
    build: .
    volumes:
      - app:/usr/src/app # the volume is defined at the end of this file
    ports:
      - 5001:5000

volumes: # You should add this and the following line
    app: # you can define any name
```

for more information, you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248988/how-do-named-volumes-work-in-docker) link.

Comment: this answer is no longer accurate, in my experience. It is possible to use bind mounts with ubuntu.

Comment: This caused my project files to be cached on the container even if I rebuild, see named docker volume not updating using docker-compose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678042/named-docker-volume-not-updating-using-docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: I did not have any issues with ubuntu and `docker-compose`. It is possible that there were problems with ubuntu images previously, however, I did not find that to be accurate. Additionally, if you're using a `virtual environment` in a docker container, you may need to specifically tell `docker-compose` not to look for your virtual environment file on the host.

---

I am posting this **under this question specifically** because of the comments and answers about ubuntu not working correctly with `docker-compose` bind mounts.

For whom it may help: if you are using a `virtual environment` inside your docker container, and you are using bind mounts, you may need to specify to have `docker-compose` NOT look for your virtual environment folder. This ensures that your virtual environment inside your container has the correct packages, paths, etc.

Example `dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim AS BUILDER

...# omitted code

ENV USERNAME=usr
ENV HOMEDIR=/home/$USERNAME
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=$HOMEDIR/$VENV

# ... omitted code

WORKDIR $HOMEDIR

# Create virtual environment and activate it
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements-dev.txt ./constraints.txt ./

# Install python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt -c constraints.txt \

# ... omitted code

WORKDIR $HOMEDIR

# ... omitted code

ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/"

# ... omitted code

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "-u", "path/to/file/to/run" ]
```

example `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    # ... omitted code
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    # ... omitted code
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/home/usr # the bind mount
      - /home/usr/venv # tell docker-compose not to look for the venv folder on the host
    ports:
      # ...omitted code
    # ...omitted code
    networks:
      - ex-network
    # ...omitted code

networks:
  ex-network:
```

I was able to get ubuntu and bind mounts working properly with the above configuration by executing the standard `docker-compose up --build`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using docker-machine with a virtualbox driver on Ubuntu. It was due to my project's directory not being shared with the docker-machine. To fix it, `cd` into your project root and specify the following flag when creating your environment: `--virtualbox-share-folder=="$PWD:$PWD"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, below is how I finally solved it.

Original code

```
 services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Changed the volume setting a little bit:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```